# Mask quiver plot with imshow in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a quiver plot I am showing with a contour plot underneath it. These are both defined by 2-D arrays.

I want to be able to "draw" objects on top of the graph, for example overlay a 10x10 black square somewhere onto the plot. The object should be black and the rest of the graph shouldn't be hidden.

```
plt.contourf(X, Y, h)
plt.colorbar()
plt.quiver(X[::2,::2], Y[::2,::2], u[::2,::2], v[::2,::2])
plt.show()
```

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Favo's answer shows the way, but to draw polygons (and potentially only rectangles), you don't need to bother with `Path`. Matplotlib will do that for you. Just use the `Polygon` or `Rectangle` classes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

# Directly instantiate polygons
coordinates = [[0.5,0.6],[0.5,0.7],[0.55,0.75],[0.6,0.7],[0.6,0.6]]
poly = plt.Polygon(coordinates, facecolor='black')
ax.add_patch(poly)

# If you just need a Rectangle, then there is a class for that too
rect = plt.Rectangle([0.2,0.2], 0.1, 0.1, facecolor='red')
ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

So to achieve your goal just create a black rectangle to "cover" parts of your plot. Another way would be to use masked arrays to only show parts of the quiver and contour plots in the first place:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html

Answer (score 1):

If by objects you mean polygons, you can do this.

```
verts = [
    (0., 0.), # left, bottom
    (0., 1.), # left, top
    (1., 1.), # right, top
    (1., 0.), # right, bottom
    (0., 0.), # ignored
    ]

codes = [Path.MOVETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.CLOSEPOLY,
         ]

path = Path(verts, codes)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='black')
ax.add_patch(patch)

ax.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
```

Code from Matplotlib [Path Tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/path_tutorial.html)